# keras zca_whitening - no error, no output generated

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing, keras

While using `zca_whitening`, my code gets stuck somewhere, neither it shows any error nor the output. When i skip the `zca_whitening` and apply other transformations, the code runs perfectly. I am attaching the code snippet here. Pl help me if I am doing anything wrong here :

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(zca_whitening=True)
datagen.fit(x_train)
```

where >> `x_train` is the set of training images (dim = 50 x 64 x 64 x 3) . After running `datagen.fit`, the code shows no further output or error, seems to have the process running for an infinite time period.

on the other hand these transformations work perfectly :

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=0.90,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    fill_mode='nearest',
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=True)
datagen.fit(x_train)
```

Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: can you modify x_train to have shape of (3,64,64) and then apply zca_whitening?

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thanks @AvijitDasgupta. I wonder why is it different only in case of zca_whitening.

Comment: Then I am writing this as an answer and you may accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify `x_train` to have shape `(3, 64, 64).`

You can do that by using the following code: `x_train = x_train.transpose((2,1,0))`

This is mainly due to the switching between theano and tensorflow backend. Check `dim_order` in Keras documentation.

Comment: I have the same problem, but as of 2020 this doesn't work. Passing `x_train` with shape `(3,64,64)` results in a warning by keras, that there should be 4 dimensions. Making the shape `(1,3,64,64)` results in a warning that there shouldn't be 64 colour channels. Can you give another suggestion?

Comment: Try to make (1, 64, 64, 3)

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with @Avjiit that the problem is due to wrong shape. The problem is common and as [confirmed](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/issues/55) by the keras main contributors the problem is that the zca-calculation takes very, very long, because it [uses](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/image/image_data_generator.py#L938) `numpy.linalg.svd()` which is computationally heavy even on matrices (n*m*3), n~m~100.

There are some approaches to calculate a quick approximation of the svd, like randomized svd by [scikitlearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.extmath.randomized_svd.html), truncated svd by [irlb](http://bwlewis.github.io/irlba/), Lanczos method svd, but they are not always numerically stable.

I think I have found another very simple method, that is very quick and gives exactly the same results as the standard method! It helps in case you have a data matrix with shape (m x n), where m is much smaller than n - e.g. you have much less images (m~1000) than number of pixels (n~100 x 100 x 3 = 30000 pixel). In such a case keras would calculate the `linalg.svd(sigma)`, with `sigma.shape=(30000,30000)`, which is computationally too exhausting and takes forever. But in a good approximation, instead of calculating the svd on a (n x n) matrix you could calculate it on a (m x m) matrix, by just rotating the input data X or flipping the order of the `sigma` calculation to look like `sigma = np.dot(flat_x, flat_x.T) / flat_x.shape[0]`. With this approach the calculation takes only ca. 10 sec, if m~1000 and n~30000. The good thing is that the eigenvectors of the `linalg.svd(sigma)` are the same in both cases up to a factor, see [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~aarti/Class/10701_Spring14/slides/PCA.pdf), slide 30. You could test this on a dataset of yours or on the inbuilt cifer set with `from keras.datasets import cifar10`.

The mathematical justification can be found [here](https://medium.com/@nestorarsenov/a-faster-svd-approximation-that-saves-time-and-makes-heavy-matrix-calculations-possible-310c48f5f9be) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7111/how-to-perform-pca-for-data-of-very-high-dimensionality/7144#7144). For visuality I share these images:

[image]
[image]

And below is the modified keras code for creating the zca calculations. You could use it to make modifications into your keras zca code, located [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/image/image_data_generator.py#L938). The modifications I made are to put if-clauses for transposing the data matrix, when needed:

```
from keras.datasets import cifar10
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
X = X_train[:1000]
flat_x = np.reshape(x, (x.shape[0], x.shape[1] * x.shape[2] * x.shape[3]))

# normalize x:
flat_x = flat_x / 255.
flat_x = flat_x - flat_x.mean(axis=0)

# CHANGES HAPPEN BELOW.
# if m>n execute the svd as usual
if flat_x.shape[0] => flat_x.shape[1]:
    sigma = np.dot(flat_x.T, flat_x) / flat_x.shape[0]
    u, s, _ = linalg.svd(sigma)
# and if m<n do the trnaspose trick
if flat_x.shape[0] < flat_x.shape[1]:
    sigma = np.dot(flat_x, flat_x.T) / flat_x.shape[0]
    u, s, _ = linalg.svd(sigma)
    u = np.dot(flat_x.T, u) / np.sqrt(s*flat_x.shape[0])

s_inv = 1. / np.sqrt(s[np.newaxis] + 0.1) # the 0.1 is the epsilon value for zca
principal_components = (u * s_inv).dot(u.T)
whitex = np.dot(flat_x, principal_components)
```