# keras: zca whitening gets stuck with train_datagen.fit()

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, keras

I am trying to use zca_whitening with the keras image processing option, but the calculation gets stuck and never ends. My part of the code causing the problem looks like this:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=30, zca_whitening=True)

def read_pil_image(img_path, height, width):
        with open(img_path, 'rb') as f:
            return np.array(Image.open(f).convert('RGB').resize((width, height)))

def load_all_images(dataset_path, height, width, img_ext='jpg'):
    return np.array([read_pil_image(str(p), height, width) for p in 
                                    Path(dataset_path).rglob("*."+img_ext)])

zca_dir = 'some/path/to_jpg_images/'
train_datagen.fit(load_all_images(zca_dir, height, width))
```

When I execute the above it gets stuck at `train_datagen.fit()`. There is no error message displayed. I found out if I just outcomment the zca_whitening and substitute it with `samplewise_center=True, samplewise_std_normalization=True` the code works just fine.

I thought first that maybe the directory zca_dir contains too many pictures, so I reduced them to 30. Still, same problem.
The problem appears on 2 different machines with 2 different keras versions. In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40735715/keras-zca-whitening-no-error-no-output-generated) there is the suggestion to reverse the dimension of my images from [80,80,3] to [3,80,80], but this doesn't change anything.

Do you know how I can solve this? Thanks

Comment: I have found this to be a duplicate to another question and have given there my exhaustive and informative answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40735715/keras-zca-whitening-no-error-no-output-generated/61656911#61656911